# Laravel Container Upgrade Issue

Tags: laravel, email, containers, upgrade

I am upgrading from 5.8 to 7 and I have a function that allows the smtp settings for mail to be pulled from a database.
It is from this tutorial
https://laravel-news.com/allowing-users-to-send-email-with-their-own-smtp-settings-in-laravel

```
     $this->app->bind('user.mailer', function ($app, $parameters) {
      $smtp_host = Arr::get($parameters, 'smtp_host');
      $smtp_port = Arr::get($parameters, 'smtp_port');
      $smtp_username = Arr::get($parameters, 'smtp_username');
      $smtp_password = Arr::get($parameters, 'smtp_password');
      $smtp_encryption = Arr::get($parameters, 'smtp_encryption');

      $from_email = Arr::get($parameters, 'from_email');
      $from_name = Arr::get($parameters, 'from_name');

      $from_email = $parameters['from_email'];
      $from_name = $parameters['from_name'];

      $transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport($smtp_host, $smtp_port);
      $transport->setUsername($smtp_username);
      $transport->setPassword($smtp_password);
      $transport->setEncryption($smtp_encryption);

      $swift_mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

      $mailer = new Mailer($app->get('view'), $swift_mailer, $app->get('events'));
      $mailer->alwaysFrom($from_email, $from_name);
      $mailer->alwaysReplyTo($from_email, $from_name);

      return $mailer;
     });
```

This worked in the previous version, however in Laravel 7 I am getting an error

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::__construct() must be of the type string, object given

It is failing here $app->get('view')

I have looked through the upgrade guides however I'm struggling to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compared the __construct in both version and you can see the difference.

[5.8 construct](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.html#method___construct)

at line 86
void __construct(Factory $views, Swift_Mailer $swift, Dispatcher $events = null)

[7.x construct](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.html#method___construct)

at line 103
void __construct(string $name, Factory $views, Swift_Mailer $swift, Dispatcher $events = null)

You need to update your code.